# Getting values posted by a form on target page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am new to asp.net and learning it to my own. I just want to submit a form on another asp.net page and want to retrieve all the posted values on that page! I have tried the following code (I am just testing and learning asp.net to my own so this code may have some blunders).

My Default.aspx page (submitting the form with values):

```
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" action="formtarget.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="namelab" Text="Your Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="namebox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="agelab" Text="Your Age" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="agebox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="submitbutton" Text="Submit" runat="server"/>
    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
```

The formtarget.aspx

```
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
       You Entered The Following Details!<br />
       Your Name: <asp:Label ID="namelab" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
       Your Age: <asp:Label ID="agelab" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

The formtarget.aspx.cs (here i want to access the posted values by Default.aspx page form)

```
 public partial class formtarget : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    String name = Request.QueryString["namebox"];
    String age = Request.QueryString["agebox"];

    namelab.Text = name;
    agelab.Text = age;
  }
 }
```

The code is working fine for me but the page formtarget.aspx is not showing up any values.

I know that I can use the Default.aspx.cs to get my form values but I am just learning how can I post my form to another page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.QueryString` is used to access parameters passed using `GET`; to access parameters passed via `POST` you should use `Request.Form`:

```
public partial class formtarget : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = Request.Form["namebox"];
        String age = Request.Form["agebox"];

        namelab.Text = name;
        agelab.Text = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: oki @Saeb Amini thanks for the answer and giving me detailed difference between the both Thanks again